# Como actualizar una @Column(unique=true) Hibernate Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy haciendo un programa con MVC, el problema lo tengo cuando cuando intento actualizar un campo.
Entidad

```
 @Column(unique = true)
    private String Dni;
```

Metodo de actualizar

```
 public static void actualizarUser(User u) throws AplicacionException {
    try {
        Session session = SingleSession.getSessio();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new AplicacionException("Error insertando usuario: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

no lo actualiza y lanza el error `ERROR: Duplicate entry '12345678' for key 'persona.UK_ogq8b34j6tb5sshivt4bu380b'`

He buscado información y una de ellas es utilizar  `EAGER i LAZY` pero esto funciona con `OneToMany`

Comment: Al usar unique = true estás diciendo que es único y no se puede repetir, para qué estás modificando un atributo que no se puede modificar?

Comment: Lo que puedes intentar es obtener la fila, eliminarla, y guardar una nueva fila con el nuevo dni actualizado